# Beaglebone Black and the MCP230xx CircuitPython Library

Tags: python, i2c, beagleboneblack, adafruit

I don't know how to specify the I2C Bus, because the Beaglebone Black has 3x (1x is not accessible via Header). I want to use both of them for many different I2C devices (Pin 17/18 I2C1 and Pin 19/20 I2C2)

[image: 2x I2C SCL/SDA Devices]

In the example they mention here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MCP230xx/blob/master/examples/mcp230xx_simpletest.py

```
import board
import busio

from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23008 import MCP23008

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x21)
```

They only use `mcp = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x21)` to specify the address of the I2C Device, not the specific Bus. I checked on the "busio" library if I'm able to do it there, but couldn't find a correct declaration.

EDIT:
It seems the board-library is doing this kind of stuff. By writing down `dir (board)` in a python shell it lists all accessible pins on the beaglebone black.

> > > > import board
> > > >         dir (board) ['CE0', 'CE1', 'I2C', 'LED_USR0', 'LED_USR1', 'LED_USR2', 'LED_USR3', 'MISO', 'MISO_1', 'MOSI', 'MOSI_1', 'P8_10',
> > > >         'P8_11', 'P8_12', 'P8_13', 'P8_14', 'P8_15', 'P8_16', 'P8_17',
> > > >         'P8_18', 'P8_19', 'P8_20', 'P8_21', 'P8_22', 'P8_23', 'P8_24',
> > > >         'P8_25', 'P8_26', 'P8_27', 'P8_28', 'P8_29', 'P8_3', 'P8_30', 'P8_31',
> > > >         'P8_32', 'P8_33', 'P8_34', 'P8_35', 'P8_36', 'P8_37', 'P8_38',
> > > >         'P8_39', 'P8_4', 'P8_40', 'P8_41', 'P8_42', 'P8_43', 'P8_44', 'P8_45',
> > > >         'P8_46', 'P8_5', 'P8_6', 'P8_7', 'P8_8', 'P8_9', 'P9_11', 'P9_12',
> > > >         'P9_13', 'P9_14', 'P9_15', 'P9_16', 'P9_17', 'P9_18', 'P9_19',
> > > >         'P9_20', 'P9_21', 'P9_22', 'P9_23', 'P9_24', 'P9_25', 'P9_26',
> > > >         'P9_27', 'P9_28', 'P9_29', 'P9_30', 'P9_31', 'P9_41', 'P9_42', 'SCK',
> > > >         'SCK_1', 'SCL', 'SCLK', 'SCLK_1', 'SDA', 'SPI', '**builtins**',
> > > >         '**cached**', '**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**',
> > > >         '**package**', '**spec**', 'ap_board', 'board_id', 'detector', 'pin',
> > > >         'sys']

But I have no clue what is the right addressing of the board.pin for I2C. By just handling the definet pin he throws me a error:

```
ValueError: No Hardware I2C on (scl,sda)=(P9_17, P9_18)
Valid I2C ports: ((1, I2C1_SCL, I2C1_SDA), (2, I2C2_SCL, I2C2_SDA))
```

It seems he recognize the two I2C-Bus-Lines. But I dont know how to address the second one.

Comment: The bus is being specified by the `I2C()` call.  Perhaps it's just a matter of specifying the right SCL/SDA pin numbers for the bus you want to use?  Perhaps there are constants defined in that `board` module for the second bus?

Comment: You're absolutely right sir. Found a reasonable explanation here: https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-to-circuitpython/the-board-module
But my list does not include something like SCL_2 or SDA_2 or whatsoever... 
I edited my question for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

To use I2C1:

i2c = busio.I2C(board.pin.I2C1_SCL, board..pin.I2C1_SDA)